# Из за чего не срабатывает запрос?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Скрипт для обработки почтовой формы,и для того что бы минимизировать код пришлось искать вот такого рода скрипты
почему может не срабатывать запрос?

```
setSubmitZNum('');
setSubmitZNum('2');

function setSubmitZNum(strId) {
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
     $("#af"+strId).submit(function() {
         var str = $(this).serialize();
         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "/op"+strId+".php",
             data: str,
             success: function(msg) {
                 if (msg == 'OK') {
                     result = '<div class="notification_ok"><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true" style="color: #fff;"></i>Спасибо! Наш менеджер с вами свяжится в ближайшее время.</div>';
                     $("#fieldsop").hide();
                 } else {
                     result = msg;
                 }
                 $('#noteop').html(result);
             }
         });
         return false;
     });
 });
}
```

Я хочу что бы одни кодом можно было обрабатывать несколько форм!

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
     $("#af).submit(function() {
         var str = $(this).serialize();
         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "/op.php",
             data: str,
             success: function(msg) {
                 if (msg == 'OK') {
                     result = '<div class="notification_ok"><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true" style="color: #fff;"></i>Спасибо! Наш менеджер с вами свяжится в ближайшее время.</div>';
                     $("#fieldsop").hide();
                 } else {
                     result = msg;
                 }
                 $('#noteop').html(result);
             }
         });
         return false;
     });
 });
```

Comment: Что именно не срабатывает? У вас рабочий скрипт, который отправляет запрос.

Comment: @Ofer я не пойму, но получается так что не доходит до обработчика запрос. А тупо перезагружает страницу при нажатии на кнопку, а должен аяксом отправлять и получать ответ.

Comment: Вам не нужен `document.ready` внутри функции `setSubmitZNum` , он там не срабатывает

Comment: @br3t А что нужно, чем заменить?

Comment: @br3t Почему не сработает? Очень даже сработает.

Comment: Убрать его вообще, код из него вставить в функцию

Comment: Зачем вы добавляете обработчики внутрь функции? Вам не все такие формы нужно ajax'ом обрабатывать?

Comment: @br3t я хочу все добавить! может это можно по другому решить  я  скину чистый код.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уберите вложенные обработчики, сгруппируйте формы по классу:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".mailform").submit(function() {
    var id = $(this)[0].id;
    var strId = id.replace(/^af/, '');
    var str = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "https://acs.com.ua/wp-content/plugins/opros-list/op" + strId + ".php",
      data: str,
      success: function(msg) {
        if (msg == 'OK') {
          result = '<div class="notification_ok"><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true" style="color: #fff;"></i>Спасибо! Наш менеджер с вами свяжится в ближайшее время.</div>';
          $("#fieldsop").hide();
        } else {
          result = msg;
        }
        $('#noteop').html(result);
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="mailform" id="af">
  <input id="i1" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
<form class="mailform" id="af2">
  <input id="i2" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
<div id="noteop"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас выполняется стандартное поведение формы - отправка запроса. Вам нужна его предотвратить, добавьте в обработчик сабмита

```
 $("#af"+strId).submit(function(event) {
     event.preventDefault()
     var str = $(this).serialize();
```

Comment: Все также как и было